# Complex trigonometric equation

Tags: complex-numbers, self-learning

> *Find a solution to the equation $\tan(z)=7i$ which satisfies the condition $0<\Re(z)< \pi$}*
>   We use the $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{zi}-e^{-zi}}{2i}$ and $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{xi}+e^{-xi}}{2}$.

Here is what I have done. Are both the reasoning **and** solution of the problem correct?

\begin{align*}
LHS&=\tan(z) \\
&=\frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)} \\
&=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{iz}}{i\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)} \\
&=i\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{1+e^{2iz}}
\end{align*}
So, 
\begin{equation}
\tan(z)=7i \iff i\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{1+e^{2iz}}=7i
\end{equation}
This can be simplified to
\begin{equation}
e^{2iz}=-\frac{3}{4}
\end{equation}
Now, we use the definition $\log(z):=\log(|z|)+\arg(z) i$ **and** the fact $0<\Re(z)<\pi$ to get:
\begin{equation}
2iz=-\log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)+\pi i \iff z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\log\left( \frac{4}{3}\right)
\end{equation}
Thus, the answer is $z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\log\left( \frac{4}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Yes, everything is correct.